# How to sum the values in an array, slice, or Vec in Rust?

Tags: rust

> Editor's note: This question's example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and references types and methods no longer found in Rust. The answers still contain valuable information.

The following code

```
let mut numbers = new_serial.as_bytes().iter().map(|&x| (x - 48));
let sum = numbers.sum();
```

results in the following error:

```
std::iter::Map<,&u8,u8,std::slice::Items<,u8>>` does not implement any method in scope named `sum`
```

What must I do to sum an array of bytes?

The following works:

```
for byte in new_serial.as_bytes().iter() {
    sum = sum + (byte - 48);
}
```

Comment: In `|&x| (x - 48)`, those parentheses are unnecessary; `|&x| x - 48` will work fine.

Comment: You can write `sum += byte - 48;` for the manual loop. Also, you use a manual fold: `numbers.iter().fold(0, |s, &x| s + x - 48)`.

Comment: This question is now obsolete, for `sum` is on `Iterator`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) was stabilized in Rust 1.11.0. You can get an iterator from your array/slice/`Vec` and then use `sum`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let sum: u8 = a.iter().sum();
    println!("the total sum is: {}", sum);
}
```

Of special note is that you need to specify the type to sum into (`sum: u8`) as the method allows for multiple implementations. See [Why can't Rust infer the resulting type of Iterator::sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41017140/155423) for more information.

---

Applied to your original example:

```
let new_serial = "01234";
let sum: u8 = new_serial.as_bytes().iter().map(|&x| x - 48).sum();
println!("{}", sum);
```

As an aside, it's likely more clear if you use `b'0'` instead of `48`.

Answer (score 24):

If performance is important, consider using an implementation that helps the compiler at producing SIMD instructions.

For example, for `f32`, using 16 lanes (total of 512 bits):

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

const LANES: usize = 16;

pub fn simd_sum(values: &[f32]) -> f32 {
    let chunks = values.chunks_exact(LANES);
    let remainder = chunks.remainder();

    let sum = chunks.fold([0.0f32; LANES], |mut acc, chunk| {
        let chunk: [f32; LANES] = chunk.try_into().unwrap();
        for i in 0..LANES {
            acc[i] += chunk[i];
        }
        acc
    });

    let remainder: f32 = remainder.iter().copied().sum();

    let mut reduced = 0.0f32;
    for i in 0..LANES {
        reduced += sum[i];
    }
    reduced + remainder
}

pub fn naive_sum(values: &[f32]) -> f32 {
    values.iter().sum()
}
```

for

```
let values = (0..513).map(|x| x as f32).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

the above is 10x faster than `values.iter().sum()` on my computer:

```
simd_sum             time:   [77.341 ns 77.773 ns 78.378 ns]
naive_sum               time:   [739.97 ns 740.48 ns 740.97 ns]
```

and ~10% slower than using `packed_simd2` (but it does not require nightly).

Comment: you can get another 20% if you compute reduced with `let reduced: f32 = sum.iter().copied().take(LANES).sum();`

Comment: cool. note that sum is a constant factor, so I assume you got 20% less for small vector of numbers.

Comment: hi, sorry, could you elaborate?  I'm fairly new to SIMD

Comment: I retested my benchmark with 513000 values instead of 514 and the difference is still around 25%. Interestingly enough, I loose any advantage if I remove the `.take(LANES)` part.